# Save image locally and then save file path as a string into a database in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How do i after i take a picture/ select an image (either will overwrite the same image variable regardless), save the image locally and then save the file path as a string into a variable to be inserted into an existing SQLite db.

Comment: MediaPicker will do most of this for you.  Your question as written is pretty broad, and most of the individual steps are fairly well documented.  Have you attempted to solve any of this on your own?  Is there a specific step or error you need help with?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same exact issue-
Here's how I got it to work

First, in your model where you've created the columns for your tables, make sure there is a property for the string that will be the imagepath

```
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
```

Then we need a method to upload and save your Image locally and another to get the file path and set it to a string. Assuming this will be in your code-behind, first add these:

```
public static string photofilename;
    public static string imagePath;
    static SQLiteConnection db;
    YourModel yourmodel = new YourModel();
```

Then the LoadPhoto method

```
async void LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
    {
        // canceled
        string PhotoPath;
        if (photo == null)
        {

            PhotoPath = null;
            return;
        }
        // save the file into local storage
        var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, photo.FileName);
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
            await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

        PhotoPath = newFile;

    }
```

Then a method to upload/save the photo (In this case I'm having the user upload from the device) which I have attached to an Upload Image button. In this method, I display the image to the Image in my XAML called ImageViewer, but this might not be necessary for you.

```
async void Image_ClickedAsync(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
            LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
            photofilename = photo.FileName;
            imagePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, photofilename);


        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            // Feature is not supported on the device
        }
        catch (PermissionException pEx)
        {
            // Permissions not granted
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
        }
        ImageViewer.Source = imagePath;
        ImageViewer.IsVisible = true;

    }
```

What this has done is open up MediaPicker, Allow the user to choose an Image and set the Image Path to the string imagePath. In my case here, I also have "ImageViewer" which is an Image in my XAML used to display the image, but we're not done yet- we haven't yet saved it to your SQLite db. Here's the method I used attached to a "Save" button-

```
        private void SaveEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "yourdb.db");
        db = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
        yourmodel.Image = imagePath;
        db.Insert(yourmodel);
    }
```

Then, assuming your using ListView or something bound to the Tables in the db, you'll have an image in your XAML like so

```
<Image  HeightRequest="340" WidthRequest="550"   x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
```

and that should do the trick- Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Ollie I love you. Thank you so much you don't understand how much i appreciate this. The amount of hours iv'e put into this.

Comment: I'm really happy it worked for you! I did literally the exact same thing in one of my apps to the letter, so I was super excited to answer ! If it worked out, go ahead and mark my answer as the correct one :)